# .collapse() error when clicking a href for the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've a strange issue with the following code:http://jsfiddle.net/rc1chhtd/4/

in practice, the first time a link is clicked, the collapse method is invoked for each div instead of just the last one. Then everything works perfectly. Any hints?

**HTML**

```
    <div class="col-md-3">

        <p class="lead">Menu</p>

        <div id="sidebar" class="list-group"> 

                <a href="#" class="list-group-item active" name="dashboard">
                    <i class="icon-dashboard"></i> Dashboard
                </a>

                <a href="#" class="list-group-item" name="a-s-c">
                    <i class="icon-group"></i> Arte Storia e Cultura
                </a>


                <a href="#enogastronomia" class="list-group-item"  data-parent="#sidebar" name="enogastronomia">
                    <i class="icon-group"></i> Enogastronomia
                    <span class="badge bg_danger">3</span>
                </a>

                    <div id="enogastronomia" class="list-group subitem collapse">    

                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            <i class="icon-caret-right"></i> Sub 1
                        </a>

                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            <i class="icon-caret-right"></i> Sub 2
                        </a>

                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            <i class="icon-caret-right"></i> Sub 3
                        </a>

                    </div> 

                <a href="#" class="list-group-item" name="artigianato">
                    <i class="icon-group"></i> Artigianato
                </a>


                <a href="#dovedormire" class="list-group-item"  data-parent="#sidebar" name="dovedormire">
                    <i class="icon-group"></i> Dove Dormire
                    <span class="badge bg_danger">4</span>
                </a>

                    <div id="dovedormire" class="list-group subitem collapse">    

                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            <i class="icon-caret-right"></i> Sub 1
                        </a>

                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            <i class="icon-caret-right"></i> Sub 2
                        </a>

                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            <i class="icon-caret-right"></i> Sub 3
                        </a>

                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            <i class="icon-caret-right"></i> Sub 4
                        </a>

                    </div> 

                <a href="#attivita" class="list-group-item"  data-parent="#sidebar" name="attivita">
                    <i class="icon-group"></i> Attività
                    <span class="badge bg_danger">4</span>
                </a>

                    <div id="attivita" class="list-group subitem collapse">    

                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            <i class="icon-caret-right"></i> Sub 1
                        </a>

                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            <i class="icon-caret-right"></i> Sub 2
                        </a>

                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            <i class="icon-caret-right"></i> Sub 3
                        </a>

                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            <i class="icon-caret-right"></i> Sub 4
                        </a>

                    </div> 

                <a href="#" class="list-group-item"  data-parent="#sidebar" name="meteo">
                    <i class="icon-group"></i> Meteo
                </a>

                <a href="#" class="list-group-item"  data-parent="#sidebar" name="numutili">
                    <i class="icon-group"></i> Numeri Utili
                </a>

                <a href="#" class="list-group-item"  data-parent="#sidebar" name="trasporti">
                    <i class="icon-group"></i> Trasporti
                </a>

        </div>

    </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $('#contenuti').load('dashboard.php');
});

$('.list-group-item').click(function (){
    var clicked=this;
    $(".list-group a").each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $(this).next('div').collapse('hide');
        if($(this).attr("name")==$(clicked).attr("name")){
            $('#contenuti').load($(this).attr("name")+'.php');
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(this).next('div').collapse('show');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Just a note: Your click handler should probably be inside the DOM ready handler too (or changed to a *delegated* event handler).

Comment: Sorry, check the edit.

Comment: I think there are some issues with the new Fiddle... at the first click continues to open all the divs

Comment: Have you update the fiddle?

Comment: Found the problem. Looks like a bug in the initial state of `div`s using `collapse`. Answer updated to work around this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some styling issues, but I suggest you change the logic to more like this:

**JSFIddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/rc1chhtd/7/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#contenuti').load('dashboard.php');

    $('.list-group-item').click(function () {
        var $clicked = $(this);
        // Hide any active divs (only)
        $(".list-group a.active").removeClass("active").next("div").collapse("hide");
        // Find the target anchor based on the name attribute in the clicked item
        var $targeta = $('.list-group a[name="' + $clicked.attr("name") + '"]').addClass("active");
        // Load the panel based on the clicked item
        $('#contenuti').load($(this).attr("name") + '.php');
        // then open the clicked div
        $targeta.next('div').collapse('show');
    });
});
```

If there is any chance you will be adding items dynamically, change the click handler to a delegated event handler *attached to a non-changing ancestor element - `document` being the default*):

```
    $(document).on('click', '.list-group-item', function () {
```

**Update:** There appears to be a bug in `collapse`. If the item has never been shown/collapsed then calling `collapse("hide")` seems to toggle them open. I changed the code to only hide "active" links.

Comment: Here's a link to the bug: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/7264 Could we get it re-opened?

Comment: @yayitswei: That bug is not only locked, the conversation is limited to collaborators :(